# Manually building a Google login integration flow using server-side code

Tags: authentication, google-signin

I am writing a project that lets users implement login integration for multiple web services (e.g. Google, Facebook etc.) to his/her website. I see Facebook allows us to [manually build a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow). Using this I can code everything myself and also let users use the script just by configuring it a bit (like setting app_secret and app_id). I am looking for a similar thing in Google. I don't wanna use the SDK because if I do that for multiple OAuth providers, then I think I'll mess things a lot. I also want to keep the client (JavaScript) side code at a minimum. So, can I build a manual login flow for Google, as I can for Facebook?

Answer (score 7):

This information is given on the following page: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent (select the **OAUTH 2.0 ENDPOINTS** tabs)

Some excerpts:

- The OAuth endpoint is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`
- Token is returned like this: `https://oauth2.example.com/callback#access_token=4/P7q7W91&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`
- You can validate the token by using the `tokeninfo` endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>`